# Docker DNS setup on VPS

Tags: networking, dns, docker

I have a VPS with static IP address (108.1.2.3 for ex). On this server I have a two docker containers with separate IP (10.1.2.3 and 10.1.2.4 for ex). And I have two domains: domain1.com and domain2.com.
My question is: how I can setup a DNS server for this two domains?
I need to point domain1.com to 10.1.2.3, domain2.com to 10.1.2.4 and have an access through browser for each domain.

I found a [solution](https://github.com/oskarhane/dockerpress), but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Which part isn't working? It looks like you have the right solution, two containers on two ports, forwarding to their own port 80s, with nginx forwarding to the corresponding ports based on the domain name it receives.

Comment: That script works perfectly, but! As it said "if you already pointed the A-record in the DNS to this servers IP". In that way I have only one IP address for each instance. Only port is different. What if I have 66k container? It's sick, but what if?:-) In a better way in need to provide user his own IP address.

Comment: I found a second problem. Each time when I create a new container I need to reload nginx server. It's bad when several users will create a new containers.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you add network interfaces to the VPS and give it multiple static IPs and bind the container ports to these IPs (using `docker run -p` with `ip:port:c_port` value), you will need some kind of reverse proxy.

When using a reverse proxy such as nginx, your issue with nginx seems to be the need to reload. Please note that, you won't only need to reload every time a new container is launched, but also every time a container is restarted (if you use an nginx container internally linked to the other containers..)

What you need is service discovery and configuration listeners to reload your reverse proxy automatically such as: etcd+confd or https://consul.io/

Comment: Thanks, Vincent! That very useful!